# Comparing arrays and adding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays

```
Data = [
"year": 2001, "count": 35,
"year": 2002, "count": 15,
"year": 2005, "count": 2
]

Years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006]
```

What I want to do is: check if the `Years` exist in the `Data`, and if they don't, add "year" to the `Data`, with a "count" of 0.

All I can do so far is check that they're there.

```js
Data = [
  "year": 2001, "count": 35,
  "year": 2002, "count": 15,
  "year": 2005, "count": 2
]

Years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006]

for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  $(Years).each(function(value) {
    if (Data.indexOf(Years[value]) != -1) {
      console.log("missing one");
    };
  })
}
```

Comment: `Data` is not array. It is an `object`

Comment: @east1999 you have syntax errors in your Data variable. Are these actual representations of what you've written in your own code? Or was this a typo in the question you posted here only? (and to the editors, let OP clarify this before assuming so and 'fixing' the code).

Answer (score 2):

If I assume your `Data` is an array of objects, then you can proceed like this:

```js
const Data = [
  {"year": 2001, "count": 35},
  {"year": 2002, "count": 15},
  {"year": 2005, "count": 2}
];

const Years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006];

Years.forEach(x =>
{
    if (!Data.some(({year}) => year === x))
        Data.push({year: x, count: 0});
})

console.log(Data);

// If you need to sort by year, then you could do this:

Data.sort((a,b) => a.year - b.year);
console.log(Data);
```

If you are searching for performance, then you can first create a [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of already existing years to improve the pushing algorithm later.

```js
const Data = [
  {"year": 2001, "count": 35},
  {"year": 2002, "count": 15},
  {"year": 2005, "count": 2}
];

const Years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006];
const dataYears = new Set(Data.map(({year}) => year));

Years.forEach(x =>
{
    if (!dataYears.has(x))
        Data.push({year: x, count: 0});
})

console.log(Data);
```

Comment: This becomes (potentially) extremely unperformant with large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You may cycle on Years:

```js
Data = [
    {"year": 2001, "count": 35},
    {"year": 2002, "count": 15},
    {"year": 2005, "count": 2}
];

Years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006];
for (var i = 0; i < Years.length; i++) {
    if(!Data.find((e) => e.year == Years[i])) {
        Data.push({'year':  Years[i], 'count': 0})
    }
}

console.log(Data);
```

Comment: This worked right away for me! I need to test this with the larger set. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use includes and push it when includes returns false

```js
for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  if(!Years.includes(Data[i].year)) years.push(Data[i].year)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is invalid rn, it should be an array of objects:

```
data = [
{"year": 2001, "count": 35},
{"year": 2002, "count": 15},
{"year": 2005, "count": 2}
]
```

then you can compare:

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length;  i++){
    if(years.includes(data[i].year){
       data[i].count++;
    }
}
```

PS: your variables should be camel cased to avoid confusion of being a class.

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate the `years` and splice the missing years into the `data` array.

```js
var data = [{ year: 2001, count: 35 }, { year: 2002, count: 15 }, { year: 2005, count: 2 }],
    years = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006];

years.forEach((i => year => {
    if (i >= data.length || year < data[i].year) {
        data.splice(i, 0, { year, count: 0 });
    }
    i++;
})(0));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```